Trying to Simulate Telegram app send code request
hi guys i'm trying to simulate telegram auth section this below code is in original telegram source code and i want to simulate this to get next_type parameter in response
i used telethon library but i couldn't exactly simulate it
TLRPC.TL_codeSettings settings = new TLRPC.TL_codeSettings();
            settings.allow_flashcall = simcardAvailable && allowCall && allowCancelCall && allowReadCallLog;
            settings.allow_missed_call = simcardAvailable && allowCall;
            settings.allow_app_hash = settings.allow_firebase = PushListenerController.GooglePushListenerServiceProvider.INSTANCE.hasServices();
            if (forceDisableSafetyNet || TextUtils.isEmpty(BuildVars.SAFETYNET_KEY)) {
                settings.allow_firebase = false;
            }


                TLObject req;

                ConnectionsManager.getInstance(currentAccount).cleanup(false);

                TLRPC.TL_auth_sendCode sendCode = new TLRPC.TL_auth_sendCode();
                sendCode.api_hash = BuildVars.APP_HASH;
                sendCode.api_id = BuildVars.APP_ID;
                sendCode.phone_number = phone;
                sendCode.settings = settings;
                req = sendCode;



